# Spinnaker pipeline failing when deployment strategy is Recreate

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

When the deployment strategy is changed from "Rolling update" to "Recreate", I am facing the below error

```
Failure executing: PATCH at: https://3x.xxx.2x1.xxx/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/xxxxxx. Message: Deployment.apps "xxxxxx" is invalid: spec.strategy.rollingUpdate: Forbidden: may not be specified when strategy type is 'Recreate'. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=422, details=StatusDetails(causes=[StatusCause(field=spec.strategy.rollingUpdate, message=Forbidden: may not be specified when strategy type is 'Recreate', reason=FieldValueForbidden, additionalProperties={})], group=apps, kind=Deployment, name=xxxxxx, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=Deployment.apps "xxxxxx" is invalid: spec.strategy.rollingUpdate: Forbidden: may not be specified when strategy type is 'Recreate', metadata=ListMeta(resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Invalid, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
```

Any help on this? I am using Spinnaker 1.6.0

Answer (score 1):

There are many tickets on GitHub related to that problem: [Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24198), [Cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/268), [Spinnaker](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/1823). And in each one you can find the same answer - it is not possible to switch the update strategy of already created resources.

So, the only way is to create a new deployment with a new strategy due to the implementation of the updating process in Kubernetes.